# How to get duration between start and end date

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting Days into Human Readable Duration Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296842/converting-days-into-human-readable-duration-text)
>   [How do I calculate difference in years and months given a start and end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698091/how-do-i-calculate-difference-in-years-and-months-given-a-start-and-end)

I use (end date - start date).TotalDays it returns total days. For example, 145 days

But I don't want total days.

It is possible to convert 145 days to 3 months and 25 days something like this.

Comment: How do you define "months"? What about February?

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure out about this problem. I don't know how to define months.

Comment: @SLaks - I would think you would define it as calendar months, like "the number of month barriers crossed from start date to end date, -1 if start date's day of month > end date's day of month."

Comment: A month is approximately `30.46666` days. How do you want your rounding?

Comment: If days > 365, do you also want years, like "1 year 2 months 6 days"?

Comment: Yes, if it more than a year.

Answer (score 4):

A bit harder than it initially seems...

I suppose you could do something like this, which has the advantage of counting actual calendar months rather than estimating months to be 30days or similar.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var future = DateTime.Now.AddDays(new Random().NextDouble() * 365);
//dates above for example only

var xx = Enumerable.Range(0,int.MaxValue)
        .Select(i => new{numMonths = i, date = now.AddMonths(i)})
        .TakeWhile(x => x.date < future)
        .Last();
var remainingDays = (future - xx.date).TotalDays;
Console.WriteLine("{0} months and {1} days",xx.numMonths,remainingDays);
```

Comment: I just realised that things go wrong if future < now. You get the idea though.

Comment: +1 for using a LINQ expression instead of a `while` loop :-)

Answer (score 1):

if you assume a month to be 30 days, this below might help.

```
var start = DateTime.Today;

var end = DateTime.Today.AddDays(99);

var timeSpan = end.Subtract(start);

var months = (int)timeSpan.TotalDays / 30;

var days = timeSpan.TotalDays % 30;

var str = string.Format("{0} months, {1} days", months, days);
```

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the number of days problem in a month, just look at the years and months

```
DateTime d1 = New DateTime(2002, 1, 1);
DateTime d2 = New DateTime(2000, 10, 1);
int years = Math.Abs((d1.Year - d2.Year));
int months = ((years  * 12)  + Math.Abs((d1.Month - d2.Month)));
```

Comment: The question is about months/days. This doesn't help...

Comment: agree that the timespan does not give you anything on #months

Answer (score 0):

The difference of two `DateTime` objects results in a `TimeSpan` object. Since the time spanned by a month is not consistent among months, how would a `TimeSpan` object be represented by a number of months?

In order to calculate the number of months between two dates, you'd need to know the start date and end date ahead of time so you can calculate the actual number of months (keeping in mind leap years, etc.) between them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want years, months, days:

1. Years = max number of years you can subtract from end date such that the result is still > start date.
2. Months = max number of months you can subtract from the previous result such that the result is still > start date.
3. Days = number of days between previous result and start date.

Answer (score -3):

Try use the time span to string...